# Another url is indexed in google which has a link ending with rpid=5PO84Q269

Tags: web-hosting, web-crawlers, security

My Website is indexed in google. When i was searching for the term in google for my website i found a url placing above my websites root URL which has same url as root URL but has a weird url parameter rpid=5PO84Q269 at the end.

Searching for the the term "rpid=5PO84Q269" in google . I got many websites which has url ending with that.

So my question is what is that Url? Why is it present ? Why is it indexed in google search results

Comment: There seems to be little on 5PO84Q269. Not much to go on. If you are running WordPress I will bet it is a hack test. Some script kiddie playing around. No evidence of anything worse that I can see, but 5PO84Q269 shows up on WP sites.

Answer (score 1):

These all pages look like some kind of hacks. If you check the cached version for these pages, you most likely will see some kind of affiliate links in there in the page which imitates, that the domain is expired. Here is an example of the screenshot:
[image: Screenshor from one of the page which contains rpid=5PO84Q269 in URL]

Please check the cached version of your page in Google and check the URLs locations on your server. Maybe it will guide you to the potentially hacked files.

Have a look on the server for files like `display.cfm` `px.js` `Health_Insurance.cfm` or any other `.cfm` extension files.

Comment: Checking even cached pages can be dangerous. I do not recommend it normally. Cheers!!

Comment: I just noticed this is an expired domain. Affiliate links are not uncommon on these sites.